# AVFoundation not working properly on ios5

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, ios5

i started using ios 5 on my app and what i found is that avfoundation is not working properly.
i have standard code from https://web.archive.org/web/20160512235332/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010192

when running i have this error: : CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0

i cheched and in:

```
 - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
```

sampleBuffer is nil.
Whats wrong with this?

Comment: post your code where to use CGBitmapContextCreateImage

Comment: `iOS 5` is under NDA. Please ask this in the developer forums.